# Stop detailInit collapse when adding a new row to the grid?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a grid that has a grid in the detailInit and when I add a new row to the grid in the detailInit the detailInit collapses.

How can I stop it from collapsing when a new record is added? I have tried using e.preventDefault() on the button click event of adding a new row but that didn't work out.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot prevent it from collapsing because every time you change something to the data it automatically rebinds and redraw the table.

What you can do however is to capture the rebinding, find the opened details and after the binding finish reopen them:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Kendo UI Snippet</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.1017/styles/kendo.common.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.1017/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.1017/styles/kendo.silver.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.1017/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css"/>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.1017/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="example">
    <div id="grid"></div>

    <script>
        let data = [{id: 1, FirstName: "Nancy", LastName: "Davolio", orders: [{title: 1}, {title: 2}]}];

        $(document).ready(function () {
            let expanded = [];

            var element = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                dataSource: data,
                toolbar: [{name: "create"}],
                height: 600,
                detailInit: detailInit,
                editable: true,
                columns: [
                    {
                        field: "id",
                        title: "id",
                    },
                    {
                        field: "FirstName",
                        title: "First Name",
                        width: "110px"
                    },
                    {
                        field: "LastName",
                        title: "Last Name",
                        width: "110px"
                    },
                    {command: ["destroy"]},
                ],
                dataBinding: function (e) {
                    expanded = $.map(this.tbody.children(":has(> .k-hierarchy-cell .k-i-collapse)"), function (row) {
                        return $(row).data("uid");
                    });
                },
                dataBound: function (e) {
                    this.expandRow(this.tbody.children().filter(function (idx, row) {
                        return $.inArray($(row).data("uid"), expanded) >= 0;
                    }));
                },
            });

        });

        function detailInit(e) {
            $("<div/>").appendTo(e.detailCell).kendoGrid({
                dataSource: {
                    transport: {
                        read: function (options) {
                            options.success(e.data.orders);
                        },
                    }
                },
            });
        }
    </script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```